# Custom tab bar resizes when ever the other tab bar item is clicked

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

This is my tab bar when ever I launch my simulator.

[image]

But, when ever I click the other tab bar items, the other icons changes as shown below:

[image]

I want my tab bar icons to look like the first picture even if I click other tab bar items. Need help! 
(I am new to IOS)

Comment: Your images need to be .pdf 25x25. Are they?

Comment: no, its in png format.

Comment: check for selectedImage property

Comment: @ReinierMelian I checked it, it has the same image i want to show in tab bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For custom tab bar images, you *have to* use a .pdf file with the dimensions of 25x25.
You can read more about this on [Apple's Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/icons-and-images/custom-icons/).

Comment: By the way it works even if the dimension is not 25x25, anyways thanks mate!

Comment: Hey can you tell me how to make the home button highlighted when i launch the app? currently, the calendar get highlighted whenever i launch my app.

Comment: Sure! You have to select the tab bar item and then make it initially selected, I believe (can't check right now). Alternatively, you could do that programmatically.