# Tab Bar Selected item color issue Swift ios

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

When i select image then its color convert to blue but should be like original  image.And other button as its is. 
[image]

Comment: From the image it doesn't seem a standard UIToolBar, could you please update the question with the library that you're using?

Comment: https://swift.unicorn.tv/screencasts/create-an-animated-tabbar I follow this article

Comment: https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar

Comment: But this issue comes without lib also

Comment: You need to provide a selected image with clear background for this. @Shahbaz Akram

Comment: Please share your code when you tap over the centre tab item.

Comment: there is no any code in file its just storyboard settings.

Comment: @DheerajD is this issue due to image background?

Comment: Seems. Please make it clear.

Comment: Is that fixed. @Shahbaz Akram

Comment: If you want to change selected tab color. You need to change imageTint color in UITabbar.

Comment: Is the image a PDF?

Comment: @LinusGeffarth  image is in png.

Comment: See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48850835/3397217) to a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have added the image name in both "SelectedImage" and "Image" options of tab bar item. Look at the image below and you should have a transparent background image.

[image]

Comment: Then it should work. Try removing and adding the images again

Comment: i add again but selected image not appear

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168633/discussion-between-suganya-marlin-and-shahbaz-akram).

Comment: you should have a transparent background image and not a colored one

Answer (score 0):

You should set the images for selectedImage of the tabbar items:

```
 viewController.tabBarItem.image = UIImage(named: "bla-bla")
 viewController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "bla-bla")
```